# MonoDevelop 2.8 Can't set iOS Application Target to iPad

Tags: .net, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Using MonoDevelop 2.8 select **project** > **options** > **iOS Application Target**

In the **Devices:** drop-down box I am not able to set the device to iPad is there a fix soon ? If I select another option other then iPad. I can never set the drop-down to iPad. I am needing to port this for a customer is there any fixes available soon ?

Comment: In the Devices dropdown there should be three options: "iPhone/iPod", "iPad" and "Universal". You're saying you don't see "iPad" there?

Comment: No I am not able to select iPad in the dropbox. It defaults too Universal everytime.

Comment: It's a bug in MonoDevelop (we've found and fixed it), it should be resolved in the next release.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your diligence.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug but you can also workaround it.

In the project Options, iPhone Application, select the **Advanced** tab then expand the "Targeted device family" and click the **-** (minus sign) to remove the "String 1" value.

If you go back to the **Summary** tab you'll see that the device is now set to **iPad**.